# How to get column name on image button clicked in column header?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application where I need to work on datagrid ,in column header I have added image button to each column which when clicked should pop up with that specific column name and other details.
Currently I have done this:

```
void data1_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
 {
    EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Button), Button.ClickEvent, new     RoutedEventHandler(btnFilterImage_Click) );
  }


 private void btnFilterImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)      
 {
     viewModel.OnYieldDistinctValues(reportDatagrid.Columns.ToString());
     lstYield.ItemsSource = viewModel.TextFilters;
     popYield.Placement = PlacementMode.MousePoint;
     popYield.IsOpen = true;
 }
```

My question is how can I get the particular column name in btnFilterImage_Click.
Please help.!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast `sender` to `Button` and find its VisualParent using [`FindVisualParent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type) till you get column.